# Is this a dangling participle?

Tags: dangling-participles

Exploring the significant characters, consider their strengths and weaknesses.

Is this a dangling participle?  Currently, my two English teachers disagree.  One says that the subject is implied and it isn't incorrect grammar, and the other says that there is no subject.

Does anybody know for sure?

Answer (score 4):

The "you" is implied in that sentence, so it is perfectly grammatical. In essence it is an imperative that says

> Exploring the significant characters, [you] consider their strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: And since the subject of a participial adverbial clause like this one (the type most infamous for its tendency to produce dangling participles) is always implicitly the same as in the finite clause that follows, the subject of both the imperative and the participle is ‘you’—which is exactly as it should be.